# Mac command line can not use Pip after change the link of python3.4

Tags: python, macos

When I type pip in terminal of MAC:

```
~ $ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
```

This is the PATH

```
~ $ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/suqi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/suqi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/suqi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/suqi/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [pip for you Python 3.4 installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html).

Also before using pip [create a virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments).